# Sql Server 2008 and Counting Rows from Different Tables with Different RowCounts

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

[image]Good day. Does anyone know how to extract data with different rowcounts from different tables?

I am calling from 3 tables and in one of the tables there are more than one row for each corresponding ID. I need to select the top 6 of each ID but the table i am joining has multiple rows with the same ID's. I need these rows. So i need to call for the top 6 but in actuality it may be more than 6 rows. My sample code is below. I am sending this to VB and 
it would like to see 6 batches of data however each batch will have a different number of rows. Here is my procedure thank you.

(NOTE** The problem I am getting is when I to run this Queuery it gives me my 6 rows but if the Roastprofile ID from RPG has lets say 3 of the same then I will get 6 rows but with 2 profile IDs . I need to LIMIT the rows or something where the PK_RoasterQueueSequenceID has 6 different IDs but there may be more than one row of each . So There are more than 6 rows buts its limited to 6 IDS ordered by the date....if this makes sense.)

NOTE* Its  like I want duplicates from that table but i dont want them to count in my rowcount.

```
    USE [Product];


GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON;


GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;


GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [Controls].[spTestGETBatchToPLC]
@SuperSackID INT OUTPUT, @POINTER1 INT
AS
SET NOCOUNT OFF;
DECLARE @PublishedStartDateTime AS SMALLDATETIME, 
@Fk_RoasterQueueSequenceID AS INT, 
@Pk_RoasterQueueSequenceID AS INT, 
@RETURN AS INT;
IF @POINTER1 = 1
    BEGIN
        SELECT   TOP 6 PK_RoasterQueueSequenceID,
                       RoasterNumber,
                       RoastProfile,
                       RoastDescription,
                       ChargeWeight
        FROM     wip.RoasterQueueSequence AS TRQS
                 INNER JOIN
                 wip.schedule AS s
                 ON s.fk_roasterqueuesequenceid = TRQS.PK_RoasterQueueSequenceID
        -- inner join Specification.RoastProfileGreenBeanComponents RPG on (****This is where there my or maynot be more than one row with the same RoastProfileID) RPG.PK_RoastProfileID = trqs.RoastProfile 
        WHERE    Trqs.Status = 'Queued'
                 AND Trqs.PK_RoasterQueueSequenceID = s.FK_RoasterQueueSequenceID
                 AND Trqs.RoasterNumber = 6
        ORDER BY s.publishedstartdatetime ASC;
        SELECT   PublishedStartDateTime,
                 FK_RoasterQueueSequenceID,
                 wip.RoasterQueueSequence.PK_RoasterQueueSequenceID,
                 wip.RoasterQueueSequence.RoasterNumber,
                 wip.RoasterQueueSequence.RoastProfile,
                 wip.RoasterQueueSequence.RoastDescription,
                 wip.RoasterQueueSequence.ChargeWeight,
                 Specification.RoastProfileGreenBeanComponents.GreenBeanPercentOfCharge,
                 Specification.RoastProfileGreenBeanComponents.partno,
                 Specification.RoastProfileGreenBeanComponents.PK_RoastProfileID
        FROM     wip.Schedule, wip.RoasterQueueSequence, Specification.RoastProfileGreenBeanComponents
        WHERE    wip.RoasterQueueSequence.Status = 'Queued'
                 AND wip.roasterqueuesequence.RoastProfile = specification.RoastProfileGreenBeanComponents.PK_RoastProfileID
                 AND wip.RoasterQueueSequence.PK_RoasterQueueSequenceID = wip.Schedule.FK_RoasterQueueSequenceID
                 AND wip.RoasterQueueSequence.RoasterNumber = 6
        ORDER BY PublishedStartDateTime;
        SELECT @RETURN = @@rowcount
        FROM   WIP.RoasterQueueSequence;
    END
```

Comment: What database are you actually using?

Comment: For the first select, are you looking to return the top 6 schedule records for each RoasterQueueSequence record? What is the maximum number of records that this query can return? 36 (6 * 6)?

Comment: (6*7) So that Specification table may have the same profile ID 7 different times (7 different partno and percent of charge).

Comment: @ENGR024 Please see my answer below. I'll try to put something together using your sample data later tonight. If you set up a SQLfiddle, that would also be helpful.

Comment: That would be very helpful. I would appreciate it greatly. I am trying to use the following example you provided me with. Im just getting a litte stuck because im including 3 tables in my CTE and for some reason SQL doesnt like how i am calling the procedure. Thank you for your time

Comment: Is the relationship between RoasterQueueSequence and Sequence 1-to-1? What tables are we looking at in the image you posted? Can we see some data from the third table?

Comment: Also, can you just post the create statements for the 3 tables? I can't tell which fields are where.

Comment: It seems like Pivot tables could work on this particular instance. Does this sound right? Using CTE, it takes nearly 20 seconds to finish executing. A loop every 15 seconds will be checking an event detector that runs these procedures; so I need to use something that executes fast. Can I inner 3 tables and one of them being a pivot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use a CTE and the `ROW_NUMBER` function. The basic approach is to number every record in the FK table (the many in the one-to-many relationshop) over the Primary Key, and then drop off every record with a number above the threshold (in this case 7). You also use a GROUP BY against to know which PK records to include. For example, say we are dealing with Orders and OrderItems, your query would look something like this:

```
;WITH myCTE AS (
    SELECT 
         OrderDetailID,
         OrderID,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OrderID ORDER BY OrderDetailID)
            as [OrderItemCount]
    FROM OrderDetails
) 
SELECT * 
FROM myCTE 
WHERE 
    --Get up to 7 details
    OrderItemCount < 8
    --Get up to 6 orders
    AND OrderID IN (
       SELECT TOP 6 OrderID FROM myCTE GROUP BY OrderID ORDER BY OrderID DESC
    )
ORDER BY
    --Most recent orders first
    OrderID DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to use a subquery to get the top 6 records from RoasterQueueSequence and join the result to the other tables.

```
select x.*,...
from
(SELECT TOP 6 PK_RoasterQueueSequenceID,
                       RoasterNumber,
                       RoastProfile,
                       RoastDescription,
                       ChargeWeight
        FROM     wip.RoasterQueueSequence AS TRQS
        INNER JOIN 
                 wip.schedule AS s
                 ON s.fk_roasterqueuesequenceid = TRQS.PK_RoasterQueueSequenceID
        WHERE    Trqs.Status = 'Queued'
                 AND Trqs.PK_RoasterQueueSequenceID = s.FK_RoasterQueueSequenceID
                 AND Trqs.RoasterNumber = 6
) as x
inner join ...
```